# Keep search bar cancel button tint color even when keyboard dismiss

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I have a search bar with cancel button in my navigation bar and when keyboard dismisses, my cancel button changes color and become inactive until I click on it again. Is there a way to keep my cancel button state the same every time?

This is before I dismiss keyboard

[image]

and this is after I dismiss keyboard

[image]

I want my cancel button stay the same before and after keyboard dismissal. Thank you for your help!

Comment: From a UX point of view, that doesn't sound like a very intuitive behaviour.  You can't cancel the search bar entry if it isn't active, so it shows a disabled state.

Answer (score -1):

I think you you can’t ,the way i did it is made  button on the right with a width ,when the user press on search bar,the button width change,and even if the the user search and dissmiss keyboard it still active,but when pressed the width is bacl to zero,and search bar is end edliting[image]
[image]
Then when cancel is pressed just make width of  it is zero

implementaion:

1-add you a button to the right of tabbar-for constrains for the button:your desired bottom contrain,and width is zero,your desired height,trailing is also zero.

2-for tab bar constrains: trailing must be zero,the rest as you like

3- dont forget to use `UISearchBarDelegate`

4-in viewdidload set `yoursearchbar.delegate = self`

5-

```
 func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
        //wcha.hey = hello.text!
        this will fire when tuching search bar for first time
        self.allview.layoutIfNeeded()
             yourcancelbutton.constant = your desired width

        }
```

6-

```
 @IBAction func yourcancelbutton(_ sender: Any) {

         yourbutton.constant = 0
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

Comment: Can you show me how you do that? It would help a lot

Comment: hey,if you have anyother question please feel free to ask